# Google Maps rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have a CRUD for "Imovels" (properties), so in the data base I have the address in different fields. That is:

```
<%= f.text_field :logradouro %> # street name
<%= f.number_field :numero %> # number
<%= f.collection_select :bairro_id, @bairros, :id, :nome, {} %> # neighborhood
<%= f.collection_select :cidade_id, @cidades, :id, :nome, {} %> # city
```

I am using the gem gmaps4rails for show the location on the map. I follow the tutorial on the gem documentation but the map doesn't render. 

On the Puma log shows up two errors

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/underscore-min.map"):

NoMethodError (undefined method `geocoded_by' for #<Class:0x007fe7c02f2fb0>):
```

Model:

```
class Imovel < ApplicationRecord
  geocoded_by :enderecoCompleto
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Concatenate:

```
def show
    @enderecoCompleto = "#{@imovel.logradouro}, #{@imovel.cidade.nome}"
end
```

The view: 
Here I want to show the map basing on the endereçoCompleto, that is the Street Name and City. I really doesn't Know how to proceed here.

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
    <script>
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers([
        {
          "lat": 0,
          "lng": 0,
          "picture": {
            "url": "http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-32.png",
            "width":  32,
            "height": 32
          },
          "infowindow": "hello!"
        }
      ]);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

If I let that code on the Model, the returned error is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `geocoded_by' for #<Class:0x007fe7c02f2fb0>):
```

How I mentioned above.
How can I render this map basing on the address in the database (without latitude and longitude) ?

After the help of @simple lime the geocoded problem was solved, but now the page render but the map doesn't show up. Actually messed up the other javascript code. Seems to be something relationed with the turbo links.

On the view:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&callback=initMap">
</script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

On the application.js:

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
```

On the console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the gem](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) + the youtube video on it's GitHub page. It [appears](https://youtu.be/R0l-7en3dUw?t=30) you need to install the `geocoder` gem as well. That's what giving you the `geocoded_by` method.

Looking at the [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), if you add `latitude:float longitude:float` to your model, it should automatically fetch and update those in the `after_validation :geocode` you have in your model. From there, you can just pass your `latitude` and `longitude` to your view and replace

```
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
```

with them. Make sure to read through the `geocoder` gem page, got a couple of useful things on there.

### Edit

For the newest issue, I'm not great with javascript, but I'd try removing the `async defer` and that `&callback=initMap` from your google maps javascript tag (since you don't have a function defined with that name).

#### Original answer, may have been a typo in the question not an actual problem with the code.

The `NoMethodError` is being caused by a typo `gecoded_by` should probably be `geocoded_by`. The `RoutingError` is just for a source map file which shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I really has write wrong, but after I correct that, the error continues.

Comment: We'd need to see more of your model and view, if that doesn't fix your issue. At least the relevant parts of your model for the gem, the html you are trying to render the map into and the javascript that's being used. Also, by "without latitude and longitude" are you trying to not store those at all? Glancing through the gem it looks like you'd need them (could be wrong, never used it myself)

Comment: Right, just edited the post with more information. I have no problem on store latitude on longitude, but I don't want to force the user to search for.

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that helps any

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer make me realize that in my gem file I write "geocode" instead "geocoder". I also have read that documentation and run the migration that documentation tells to. The geocoder is working just fine (thanks to you), the page renders but the map doesn't show up. I think that is some problem on the javascript. I am editing the post again.

Comment: @SuBzer0 Where is your initMap callback defined? It doesn't look like you have one and I wonder if that's somehow messing up the google script from finishing loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148711/discussion-between-subzer0-and-simple-lime).